# Color doesn't show when pasting multiple times

Tags: vba, excel

I would really appreciate if someone can help me to identify the problem with this code. The code is suppose to turn column O into red every time when "Spain" is inserted in column A. I.e. if A2 is "Spain" then O2 turns red. The code below does this job when I am writing "Spain" in A2. However, if I copy-paste "Spain" from A2 to A10, then only cell that will turn red in column O will be cell O2.

Why cells O3 to O10 don't turn red as well? How can I do that?  Must appreciated.

```
Sub columnO(d As Long)

    If Cells(d, "A") = "Spain" And Cells(d, "O") = "" Then
    Cells(d, "O").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
    Cells(d, "O").Interior.Color = RGB(1000, 1000, 1000)
    End If

    End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A5:O10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       columnO Target.row
    End If
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're doing this via VBA instead of using Conditional Formatting?

Comment: I didn't use conditional formatting because i didn't know how to make the cell i.e. O2 white when a value was inserted into it.

Comment: Conditional format formula, apply to desired range (in this case O2:O10): `=AND($A2="Spain",$O2="")`

Comment: @tigeravatar that would make a voteworthy answer :)

Comment: ^^ better than my one!

Comment: Must appreciated, tigeravatar. I will use this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, this can be done without any VBA by utilizing Conditional Formatting.  Create a new conditional format rule using a formula and apply to the desired range (in this case $O$2:$O$10):

```
=AND($A2="Spain",$O2="")
```

Comment: I just checked something now. Why cell O2 doesn't change from red to white when a value is inserted in it? @tigeravatar  Thanks

Comment: @alex2002 You probably have hard-coded some of the colours already to be red.  Just change the entire column back to not have any colouring, and it should be fine.  (The conditional formatting will still be applied to make them red, even though you have cleared the manual formatting.)

Comment: @alex2002 It does change for me.  You'll want to make sure the conditional format rule is applied properly.  Here is a [link](https://exceljet.net/lessons/how-to-use-a-formula-with-conditional-formatting) with a quick tutorial on how to use formulas with conditional formatting.

Comment: @tigeravatar The bad ones will be the ones that had the red colouring applied using the existing macro.

Comment: yes, fix that. Thanks again for all your help! @tigeravatar

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Change` event to loop through all rows in `Target`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A5:O10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        For Each r In Application.Intersect(Range("A5:O10"), Target).Rows
           columnO r.Row
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```